# Change colour of words with capital letter

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table with lots of word and need find words with capital letter and change its colour. For example:

```
A1: event 
A2: Event 
A3: Happy day
```

- and should change the colour of the words to red in A2 and A3 but in A3 just the "Happy" word. I tried to solve with conditional formatting but I failed. :) (Maybe VBA?)

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You will need VBA, and you'll only be able to do it if the contents of the cell is a string, and not the result of a formula.

Comment: You can use CF (for the whole cells) using a formula-based rule like (eg) 
 `=NOT(EXACT(A2,LOWER(A2)))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would probably skip the regex and just check against the ucase equivalent of the first character (this is just a guess, but I think it will be faster than using regex also). Like this:

```
Sub Capitalize()

Dim sheet As Worksheet
Dim cell, range As range
Dim results() As String
Dim pos As Integer

Set sheet = ActiveSheet
Set range = sheet.range("a1", sheet.range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

For Each cell In range
    pos = 1
    results = Split(cell)
    'if first char is upper then set color
    For Each r In results
        If Left(r, 1) = UCase(Left(r, 1)) Then
            cell.Characters(pos, Len(r) + 1).Font.Color = vbRed
        End If
        pos = pos + Len(r) + 1
    Next
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works like a charm. :)

Comment: Thanks wasn't sure if you need it red if any letter was capitalized - like @Naresh answer

Comment: Both solutions are proper for my task. I need finding the capitalized words at the moment, but maybe @Naresh's edition will be useful in the future. :)

Answer (score 3):

Reference - MicroSoft VBScript Regular Expressions X.X

```
Sub test()
    Dim mCol As MatchCollection
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim rngDB As Range, rng As Range
    Dim strPattern As String
    Dim s As String
    Dim i As Integer, Ln As Integer, c As Integer


    Set Ws = ActiveSheet
    Set rngDB = Ws.Range("a1", Ws.Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

    strPattern = "[A-Z][a-z]{1,}"

    For Each rng In rngDB
        s = rng.Value
        Set mCol = GetRegEx(s, strPattern)
        If Not mCol Is Nothing Then
            For i = 0 To mCol.Count - 1
                c = mCol.Item(i).FirstIndex + 1
                Ln = mCol.Item(i).Length
                rng.Characters(c, Ln).Font.Color = vbRed
            Next i
        End If
    Next
End Sub
Function GetRegEx(StrInput As String, strPattern As String) As Object
    Dim RegEx As New RegExp
    Set RegEx = New RegExp
    With RegEx
        .Global = True
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .MultiLine = True
        .Pattern = strPattern
    End With
    If RegEx.test(StrInput) Then
        Set GetRegEx = RegEx.Execute(StrInput)
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Sorry it doesn't work. It stops with "Compile error: User-defined type not defined" message.

Answer (score 3):

edited Kevin's answer if you want to check any alphabet in the word (not just first) for uppercase and highlight it red if true

```
Sub Capitalize()
Dim sheet As Worksheet
Dim cell As range, myrange As range
Dim results() As String
Dim pos As Integer

Set sheet = ActiveSheet
Set myrange = sheet.range("a1", sheet.range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

For Each cell In myrange
    pos = 1
    results = Split(cell)

    For Each r In results
        If r <> LCase(r) Then

            cell.Characters(pos, Len(r) + 1).Font.Color = vbRed
        End If
        pos = pos + Len(r) + 1
    Next
Next

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much it works even more perfect. :)