# How to hilite only a space in an excel cell or word

Tags: excel, space

Here is my problem .  I have cells in excel (or even in word) that have a space (two spaces or three spaces whatever) in front of say a number (like " 85gg") or date (or in the middle of a value in a cell such as in (My name is 007) . I want to hilite this space(s) only in a different color, to quickly show visually that aspace (or spaces exist there).

I thought I can do this in word & copy it to Excel but this does not work in Word either.
I type ( ts55dd) and try to hilite the space before the word ts55dd  in a different color.

At least you can visually see the space in between "78 90" but big proble is that one cannot see leading or trailing spaces of a value (at the very beginning or at very end, inside a cell. For example I may want 2 spaces before the beginning of value and 4 spaces at the end, after the value

Comment: You need [range.characters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.characters) .. Like [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60358361/9808063)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Naresh's answer in his second link is already very close to what you need

Answer (score 1):

I usually use this formula to know how many extra spaces were present in each cell

> (LEN(G4)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(G4,"  ",""))

You can also place this conditional formatting to highlight the cells

> ((LEN(G4)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(G4,"  ","")))>1

I was trying to identity how many double spaces are being replaced in a cell using substitute() and surrounding by Len() and subtracting that number with length of cell

In case if you are looking to remove spaces you can Trim() formula or use Find and Replace option in excel which always works for me.